# Breaking a string containing multiple paragraphs into two halves in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I had string text which I wanted to break up. I needed to send it across a Facebook messenger chat API but that API only allows 640 characters and my text is much longer. I wanted a neat solution with which I could send the text across.

I was thing of splitting that string which contains multiple paragraphs in to two  halves to the nearest full stop.

Eg

```
var str = "This is paragraph one. I need Mr. Sam to my errand. The errand must be done by him. He is the best.

Mr. Sharma is also good. Btw this is the second paragraph. I think you get my point. Sentence again. Sentence again.

Paragraph three is started. I am writing so much now. This is fun. Thanks";

//Expected output

var half1 = "This is paragraph one. I need Mr. Sam to my errand. The errand must be done by him. He is the best.

Mr. Sharma is also good. Btw this is the second paragraph."

var half2 = "I think you get my point. Sentence again. Sentence again.

Paragraph three is started. I am writing so much now. This is fun. Thanks"
```

Comment: So look at the 640 character and work your way back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var results=[];
var start=0;
for(var i=640;i<str.length;i+=640){//jump to max
 while(str[i]!=="."&&i) i--;//go back to .
  if(start===i) throw new Error("impossible str!");
  results.push(str.substr(start,i-start));//substr to result
  start=i+1;//set next start
 }
}
//add last one
results.push(str.substr(start));
```

You could walk over the string by making a 640 step forward, then going back to the last . , create a substring and repeat.

Answer (score 3):

Consider this as a base:

```
let slices = [], s;
for(let i = 0; s = a.slice(i * 640, (i+1) *  640); i++)
    slices.push(s);
```

The slices array will contain 640 char chunks of your text. But we want this to be space aware. We need to find the end of a sentence as close to that 640 mark as possible without going past it. If we want to be space aware, it'll make our lives easier to deal with *whole sentences* rather than characters:

```
// EDIT: Now, if a sentence is less than 640 chars, it will be stored as a whole in sentences
// Otherwise, it will be stored in sequential 640-char chunks with the last chunk being up to 640 chars and containing the period.
// This tweak also fixes the periods being stripped
let sentences = str.match(/([^.]{0,639}\.|[^.]{0,640})/g)
```

Here is a quick demo of that nasty regex in action: [https://jsfiddle.net/w6dh8x7r](https://jsfiddle.net/w6dh8x7r/2)

Now we can create our result up to 640 characters at a time.

```
let result = ''
sentences.forEach(sentence=> {
    if((result + sentence).length <= 640) result += sentence;
    else {
        API.send(result);
        // EDIT: realized sentence would be skipped so changed '' to sentence
        result = sentence;
    }
})
```

Comment: You got it. I did just realize though that you'll get weird behavior if any individual sentences exceed 640 characters in length, so just keep that in mind.

Comment: Also what about the last sentences? for example if there are 1626 character. only the first 1280 will be sent. What about the others?

Comment: any help on this problem?

Comment: Working on a solution. Will post an edit once it's working.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var txt = 'This is paragraph one. I need Mr. Sam to my errand. The errand must be done by him. He is the best. Mr. Sharma is also good. Btw this is the second paragraph. I think you get my point. Sentence again. Sentence again. Paragraph three is started. I am writing so much now. This is fun. Thanks'
    var p = []
    splitValue(txt, index);

    function splitValue(text)
    {
        var paragraphlength = 40;
        if (text.length > paragraphlength) 
        {
            var newtext = text.substring(0, paragraphlength);
            p.push(newtext)
            splitValue(text.substring(paragraphlength + 1, text.length))
        }
    }
```